# I'm giving a presentation on social media with a short part based on Stack Overflow. How would you describe its key principles?

Tags: discussion, meta, presentations

I'm giving a presentation on social media with a short part based on Stack Overflow. How would you describe its key principles? What are its key benefits over the traditional forum/mailing list problem resolution?

Comment: This will probably be moved to meta.stackoverflow.com.  One key feature of stackoverflow is that you do not talk about stackoverflow on stackoverflow.

Comment: I'd have to agree with magnifico

Comment: It doesn't have principles, it's all chaos built upon a phpBB framework.

Comment: Stack Overflow is just Jon Skeet's realtime brain dump

Answer (score 5):

- **Focus on Q&A over discussion** (keeps individual threads targeted at individual problems, makes them easier to find later)
- **Searchable/organizable via meta-data** (tags + titles allow fast & effective filtering of search results)
- **Community editable** (reduces the problem of new users abusing meta-data, allows incremental improvement)
- **Ranked answers** (good answers posted after poor ones can still "float to the top" vs. lost in the noise of a traditional forum / list)

Answer (score 1):

Jeff Atwood gave an excellent talk about Stack Overflow at [EclipseCon 2009](http://www.eclipsecon.org/2009/) that covered a lot of the bases and design rationale, including how certain features were inspired by [MMOs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massively_multiplayer_online_game) :)

Let me try and dig up the link.

Comment: http://ztrek.blogspot.com/2009/03/secrets-of-social-site-success.html & http://www.slideshare.net/codinghorror/eclipsecon-2009-keynote-the-social-mind-designing-like-groups-matter may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 0):

See also: https://blog.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

Also see [Joel Talks About Stack Overflow at Google](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/joel-talks-about-stack-overflow-at-google/).